# Calculating and creating percentage column from two columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a df (`Apple_farm`) and need to calculate a percentage based off values found in two of the columns (`Good_apples` and `Total_apples`) and then add the resulting values to a new column within Apple_farm called 'Perc_Good'.

I have tried:

```
Apple_farm['Perc_Good'] = (Apple_farm['Good_apples'] / Apple_farm['Total_apples']) *100
```

However this results in this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Doing

`Print Apple_farm['Good_apples']`  and `Print Apple_farm['Total_apples']`

Yields a list with numerical values however dividing them seems to result in them being converted to strings?

I have also tried to define a new function:

```
def percentage(amount, total):
    percent = amount/total*100
    return percent
```

but are unsure on how to use this.

Any help would be appreciated as I am fairly new to Python and pandas!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need convert `string` columns to `float` or `int`, because their `type` is `string` (but looks like numbers):

```
Apple_farm['Good_apples'] = Apple_farm['Good_apples'].astype(float)
Apple_farm['Total_apples'] = Apple_farm['Total_apples'].astype(float)

Apple_farm['Good_apples'] = Apple_farm['Good_apples'].astype(int)
Apple_farm['Total_apples'] = Apple_farm['Total_apples'].astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

Good_apples = ["10", "20", "3", "7", "9"]
Total_apples = ["20", "80", "30", "70", "90"]
d = {"Good_apples": Good_apples, "Total_apples": Total_apples}
Apple_farm = pd.DataFrame(d)
print Apple_farm 
  Good_apples Total_apples
0          10           20
1          20           80
2           3           30
3           7           70
4           9           90

print Apple_farm.dtypes
Good_apples     object
Total_apples    object
dtype: object

print Apple_farm.at[0,'Good_apples']
10

print type(Apple_farm.at[0,'Good_apples'])
<type 'str'>
```

```
Apple_farm['Good_apples'] = Apple_farm['Good_apples'].astype(int)
Apple_farm['Total_apples'] = Apple_farm['Total_apples'].astype(int)

print Apple_farm.dtypes
Good_apples     int32
Total_apples    int32
dtype: object

print Apple_farm.at[0,'Good_apples']
10

print type(Apple_farm.at[0,'Good_apples'])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

```
Apple_farm['Perc_Good'] = (Apple_farm['Good_apples'] / Apple_farm['Total_apples']) *100

print Apple_farm
   Good_apples  Total_apples  Perc_Good
0           10            20       50.0
1           20            80       25.0
2            3            30       10.0
3            7            70       10.0
4            9            90       10.0
```

Comment: That apple farm needs to find some better apples

Answer (score 0):

This code may helps you :

```
revenue_per_countries = df.groupby(["Country"])["Amount"].sum().sort_values()

revenue_per_countries = pd.DataFrame(revenue_per_countries)

revenue_per_countries['percent'] = revenue_per_countries['Amount']/revenue_per_countries['Amount'].sum()*100

revenue_per_countries = revenue_per_countries.sort_values(by=['percent'], ascending=False)

revenue_per_countries = revenue_per_countries.head(15)

revenue_per_countries.head(15)
```